# Sweep-line algorithm with circle intersections

Tags: segment, line-intersection

I'm trying to implement the sweep line algorithm for circle intersections in which an intersection occurs iff the euclidean distance between the circles' origins are <= the sum of both radii. (excluding circles within circles)

I reduced my problem to the sweep line algorithm by defining circles as having an entry- and end-point (the upper maxima and the lower maxima).
when arriving at an upper maxima both right- and left maxima of the circle would be added to the status. The status is ordered by the x coordinates of maxima's of the circles. [here is an example of how the boundaries look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZnFO.png)

The original sweep line algorithm lets you switch the segments' index in the status if they intersect. But in this case even when two circles intersect, they go back to their original order after a given point since they are circles and not continues lines.

I could also define the intersection as a valid intersection if the intersection point is on both halves of the circles.

I'm open for suggestion on how to define the intersection part of the algorithm. Or if there is something missing that I'm not noticing.